# Share data between two scripts on different servers

Tags: debian, python-3.5, file-sharing

Right, i have a bot that has 2 shards, each on their own server. I need a way to share data between the two, preferably as files, but im unsure how to achieve this.

> The bot is completely python3.5 based
>
> The servers are both running Headless Debian Jessie
>
> The two servers arent connected via LAN, so this has to be sharing data over the internet
>
> The data dosent need to be encrypted, as no sensitive data is shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest to achive, that is also secure is to use sshfs between the servers.